# Whats wrong with this projection (matrix)

Tags: python, projection, projection-matrix

Ive got this python code. It *should* project 8 cube corners. It doesn't tho:

```
import math

def setProjectionMatrix(angleOfView, near, far):
    scale = 1 / math.tan(angleOfView * 0.5 * math.pi / 180)

    M = [[scale, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, scale, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, -far / (far - near), -3],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]

    return M

def multPointMatrix(vin, M):
    x, y, z = vin
    nx = x * M[0][0] + y * M[1][0] + z * M[2][0] + M[3][0]
    ny = x * M[0][1] + y * M[1][1] + z * M[2][1] + M[3][1]
    nz = x * M[0][2] + y * M[1][2] + z * M[2][2] + M[3][2]
    w = x * M[0][3] + y * M[1][3] + z * M[2][3] + M[3][3]

    if w != 1 and w != 0:
        nx /= w
        ny /= w
        nz /= w

    return nx, ny, nz


#Gets coordinates of cube points and add them to *vertices*
cubeSize = 20
x, y, z = (0, 0, 50)
sh = int(cubeSize / 2)

vertices = [(x + sh, y + sh, z - sh), (x + sh, y - sh, z - sh), (x - sh, y - sh, z - sh), (x - sh, y + sh, z - sh),
            (x + sh, y + sh, z + sh), (x + sh, y - sh, z + sh), (x - sh, y - sh, z + sh), (x - sh, y + sh, z + sh)]

coords = [] #Coordinates

imageWidth = 512
imageHeight = 512

worldToCamera = [[0 for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)] 
worldToCamera[3][1] = -10
worldToCamera[3][2] = -10

angleOfView = 90
near = 25
far = 75

projectionMatrix = setProjectionMatrix(angleOfView, near, far)

for v in vertices:
    vertCam = multPointMatrix(v, worldToCamera)
    projectedVert = multPointMatrix(vertCam, projectionMatrix)

    x, y, z = projectedVert
    if x < -1 or x > 1 or y < -1 or y > 1: continue

    x = min(imageWidth - 1, int(((x + 1) * 0.5 * imageWidth)))
    y = min(imageHeight - 1, int(((1 - (y + 1) * 0.5) * imageHeight)))

    coords.append((x, y))

input(coords) #Input so the window doesn't close
```

Output:

```
[(256, 341), (256, 341), (256, 341), (256, 341), (256, 341), (256, 341), (256, 341), (256, 341)]
```

Why are all of the points the same and whats wrong? Changing the cubeSize, near and far variables does change the output, but its still all the same. This code is from [scratch a pixel](https://www.scratchapixel.com/code.php?id=4&origin=/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix), but in python.

Comment: Perhaps print/see in debugger the values of `x` and `y` before `min` operation. Looks like your `x` is very close to `0`, so you always end up with `0.5 * imageWidth` and `y` is close to `-0.33333` which gives you `0.6666 * imageHeight`. In this case you can also print/debug the value of `v` and what `multPointMatrix` operations are doing with it. Seems in at least one of them there is some saturation happening, so you always end up with the same result.

Comment: The `vertCam` variable is always the same and if I take it out, the projection kind of works. But how can I now add camera movement? isnt that what ive taken out?

Comment: Looking at `multPointMatrix` and values in `worldToCamera` it makes sense. `worldToCamera` to camera contains only 0 except for `worldToCamera[3][1]` and `worldToCamera[3][2]`. But in `multPointMatrix` the coordinates are multiplied by all matrix values except 3,1 and 3,2. So for `worldToCamera` the result does not the depend on the input - it will always be: `nx = 0`, `ny = -10` and `nz = -10` (because `w` is also always `0` in this case). Please double check the equations and the content of the matrices.

Comment: (side note: do not use `==` and `!=` comparisons for floating-point values: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html )